# What model's slot is called when Qtableview scrolled

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a `QTableView` on top of a `QSqlTableModel`. My database is sqlite.

I know `QSqlTableModel` lazily loads the data from the database (it actually loads 256 rows at a time), so when the users scrolls the view to the bottom, the model loads the 256 next rows.

I would like to know:

- What is the signal emitted when the users reaches the bottom of the view ?
- What is the model's method called to load the 256 next rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view asks the model for data by calling `data` function for all table cells that are visible. The model then queries the database if needed. How this happens in detail depends on the underlying database. The `QSqlQueryModel` documentation says that: *"if the database doesn't return the number of selected rows in a query, the model will fetch rows incrementally. See fetchMore() for more information"*. Apparently this is the case for sqlite.

The query happens in the `fetchMore` method of the model, I don't think there are any signals involved. You should be able to use the `canFetchMore` method to test if all records have been retrieved (not sure if this is want you want, perhaps you can tell us what you are ultimately trying to achieve.)

**Edit after discussion:**

You can inherit from the model and override the data method. I don't know where it's called in the view, probably in many places. You could try to look in the Qt source. If you need to do this from the view: when I look in the documentation of QAbstractScrollArea (which is an ancestor of QTableView) it seems that you can connect to a scroll bar's QAbstractSlider.actionTriggered signal to detect if the scroll bar is at the maximum.

Comment: Hum, are you sure there is no signal involved ? You answered half of my question (which is already great), the `fetchMore` method is called. But when the user scrolls the view, and reaches the bottom (his verticalScrollBar is at the really bottom), there must be a signal emitted. How the model would know when to load the next chunk otherwise ? I need to know what signal it is.

Comment: Why do you need to know what this signal is? I'm asking so that we avoid a potential [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yeah, I know what is a XY problem. But my problem is a bit complex, and it would take too much time to explain it. Also, my code is so big and interlocked that I can't provide a working example. I just need the name of this signal to intercept it, give it a supplementary parameter, and subclass the `fetchMore` method.

Comment: The view asks the model for the data in a cell by calling the `data` function for all rows and columns that are currently visible in the table. The view has a reference to its model so it can call this function directly, there is no need to use the signal-slot mechanism. If the model executes `fetchMore` and, if more rows are inserted, it will emit the `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted` signals before and after the operation. Perhaps this is useful to you. The view can ask for the current number of rows in the model with the `rowCount` method.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can probably do something with that. But you see: "The view has a reference to its model so it can call this function directly". When and how does it call this function ? I want to be there !

Comment: You can inherit from the model and override the `data` method. I don't know where it's called in the view, probably in many places. You could try to look in the Qt source. If you need to do this from the view: when I look in the documentation of `QAbstractScrollArea` (which is an ancestor of `QTableView`) it seems that you can connect to a scroll bar's `QAbstractSlider.actionTriggered` signal to detect if the scroll bar is at the maximum. These are just some ideas. Can't tell if they're useful since I don't know what your end-goal is :-)

Comment: That's perfect, that's what I needed. Can you edit your answer to add this part ?

Comment: Sure. I have added it.